# websocket duplicate sends from browser client if onclick handler over 126 size. Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

A firefox/chrome browser is sending double messages when the call to send happens inside a onclick event and the message size is over 126.  I am not sure if this is an error in webkit / firefox / chrome source. Just confirmed this bug on PHP Rachet though I am not using it. Perhaps the spec for WebSockets has recently changed?

To replicate:
Send a message large than 126 bytes from latest firefox/chrome. Look at wireshark+receiving end. Client sends 2 frames. Receiving end gets the full frame, then a busted frame with either junk or partial content.  The length in the frame headers line up though, and everything is parsed correctly.

```
recved bytes: 293
Header[1] Len: 126
BuffLen: 293 DataLen: 187 Offset: 195
[Got msg]: {"type":"chat","opcode":"sendmessage","message":"faefaefafefaefaefaefafefaefaefaefafefaefaefaefafefaefaefaefafefaefaefaefafefaefa","name":"Karl","userid":114,"compid":1}

Header[1] Len: 92
BuffLen: 293 DataLen: 92 Offset: 293
[Got msg]: �y{"�pe�C"c�t"�[op�de�C"s�dm�
sa�",�es�ge�C"f�fa�af�ae�ef�fa�fa�ae�ef�ef�fa
```

As you can see we receive 293 bytes for some reason and the first messages length is 187 bytes + 8 bytes of header. Then we hit parsing junk which is correctly identified as 92 bytes and parsed to the end of the buffer.  This does not occur with sizes under 126.

This does not happen if sending the frame inside the onconnect for example. Example:

```
BuffLen: 178 DataLen: 170 Offset: 178
[Got msg]: {"type":"chat","opcode":"sendmessage","message":"eafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffaeggaegaeaeg","name":"Karl","userid":114,"compid":1}
```

I think this might be a framework/scheduling issue, and packets should be qued for sending?

Comment: Are you sure that is not the javascript click handler that is registered twice for the same event?

Comment: I should get the same exact message twice then. Not 1 normal and 1 mangled.  Looks like a bug to me with the event handler. I disabled the double registration and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Send is not threadsafe. Unlike the documentation says. To replicate, call send twice from 2 event handlers at same time.